# Best practice to get and set network properties of minions by salt

Tags: networking, salt-stack

I want to get and set network properties those one are in this picture by salt(If I want to be more specific salt-api).
[Ubuntu network information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWcGU.png)

I know I can get some ip and netmask by salt.modules.network.interfaces and gateway from salt.modules.network.default_route and set network properties of windows machines by [WIN_IP](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.win_ip.html) but I think there must be a better way.
Also I didn't find a way to gather dns of minions yet.

thanks in advance

Comment: Getting hardware information: I would suggest you to have a look into ```salt '*' grains.items```